# Serial operations and idempotency

Tags: http

If action A is idempotent (a PUT action or similar), and action B is idempotent, then must

action A then B

produce the same result as

action B then A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not necessarily. If A and B are both idempotent, they both can change application state independently of each other. If they do so in different ways, A,B is a different operation that B,A.

For the very definition: If an operation A is idempotent, the first time the operation is invoked, application state may alter. Not so, however, on subsequent invocations. E.g. A is to result into the same application state as A,A,A,A. This also means that A,B will result into the same state as A,B,A.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll see if there are any other view points before accepting this answer in a couple of days

Comment: May I ask what it actually is you want to achieve? It seems to me like you wish to establish transactional safety over HTTP.

Comment: I have a series of logs that are uploaded by users, and I have been claiming the interpretation and persistence of data is idempotent.  However, the logs have timestamps, and depending on the order the users upload them, records are being set to various values.  So I recently began to question whether I was using the term properly.  Google searches leads to math ring theory and monoids, whatever those are.

Comment: Huh … I can't see if you are trying to avoid duplicates or lost updates here. I guess that would be very specific to your application. Ring theory and monoids are terms from discrete mathematics (although monoids are not exclusive to DM). What you see there is very essential to the nature of arithmetic operations. The definition of idempotence you may find there is a bit different from the HTTP one, though. See [RFC7231, sec. 4.2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no.

let `A` = `PUT(X, k)` and the result is X<sub>k</sub>

let `B` = `PUT(X, j)` and the result is X<sub>j</sub>

You can see, then, that `A` then `B` will result in X<sub>j</sub>, while `B` then `A` will result in X<sub>k</sub>.

Comment: Also a useful answer.